# make sound loop Alerts every five seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

I'm trying to write a simple loop sound Alerts every five seconds

How can i add it please

tweak for cydia

Tweak.xm template

```
     if (lowenabled) {
      if ([batString isEqualToString:lowbatPercent_String]) {
        if (lowplayer) {
          return;
        }

        if (lowsound == 0)
          soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Super Mario.mp3", bundlePrefix];
        else if (lowsound == 1)
          soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Super Mario 1.mp3", bundlePrefix];

        soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

        lowplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
        lowplayer.numberOfLoops = 3;
        [lowplayer play];
      } else {
        if (lowplayer) {
          lowplayer = nil;
        }
      }
    }
}
%end
```

Answer (score 0):

Include to fire timer:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(playSound:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
```

Put method in the same class:

```
- (void)playSound {
 // the code you included here that plays the sound
}
```

[Docs for NSTimer's fire method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/1414035-fire?language=objc)

Comment: [lowplayer play]; ——> goes inside playSound() where the comment is.

Comment: And everything else you did to setup lowplayer, unless you decide to setup lowplayer outside that function but it needs to be accessible throughout the entire view controller/class you’re in

Comment: Tweak.xm:36:10: warning: unused variable 'timer' [-Wunused-variable]
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer         scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 tar...
         ^

Comment: Add [timer fire]; after declaring the timer to remove that error. Let me know if that works.

Comment: agian /// . Tweak.xm:45:10: warning: unused variable 'timer' [-Wunused-variable]
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:sel...
         ^

Comment: Maybe I'll share the full code here?
Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you add [timer fire]; below? Sure share code I’ll take a look

Comment: I could not get the full code into my post so I sent you a link please

Comment: It’s just a warning, you can ignore it and it should still work. I looked at the code, you didn’t add the nstimer. The code I gave should be added right before the %end.

Comment: Try running it and ignoring the warning. [timer fire]; should remove the warning though

Comment: I added in my xcode
I sent you a link that you can add to me yourself

Comment: It does not work bro
My iPhone crashes into loop mode